# How to invoke a web service published on a service bus using ajax?

Tags: ajax, soap, soa, jdeveloper, osb

I'm working with Oracle service bus, I've currently created services with SOA in jdeveloper which I have published on the service bus that offers oracle, now I need to access them from my mobile application made in phonegap. Does anyone know how to do it?. I have used a function in ajax but it does not work:

`conectar = function () {
var url = "http://10.0.0.191:7001/OSBCapled/Proxy_Services/AutenticacionWS?WSDL"
var datos = '<soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
                            + '<soap:Header     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
                            + '</soap:Header>'
                            + '<soapenv:Body>'
                            + '<aut:requestRegistro     xmlns:aut="http://www.integracion.org/autenticacion">'
                            + '<aut:Email>'+$('#usuario').val()+'</aut:Email>'
                            + '<aut:Clave>'+$('#clave').val()+'</aut:Clave>'
                            + '</aut:requestRegistro>'
                            + '</soapenv:Body>'
                            + '</soapenv:Envelope>';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                async: false,
                data: datos,
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'text/xml',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Funciono!! " + data.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                   alert("Error"):
                },
            });
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has `?wsdl` at the end. This implies that you want the specification *of* the service, rather than sending messages *to* the service.

Remove that, and you might have more luck.

Comment: Then you need to hit the non-wsdl endpoint with a tool that inherently understands SOAP, like SoapUI to determine exactly how to get a meaningful response from the endpoint, so you can work out what you're missing from the json call.

Comment: All the values I use in the call I got them from SoapUI, the error that returns the ajax fail method is: "Not connect: Verify Network".